# Index was outside the bounds of the array error

Tags: c#

I'm currently making proxy checker with my input Textbox. I'm getting C# error:Index was outside the bounds of the array from proxy(123.34.123.45:8080).

**My codes will be...**

```
string occoultProxy = "123.34.123.45:8080";
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(occoultProxy.Split(':')[0], Convert.ToInt32(occoultProxy.Split(':')[1])); //Error at this line
// WebProxy(string Host, int Port)
```

---

*UPDATED*

I had tried another codes, but still have error code. Please help.

```
 string[] address = occoultProxy.Split(new[] { ':' });
 MessageBox.Show(address[0].ToString());
 MessageBox.Show(address[1].ToString());
 WebProxy proxyHTTP = new WebProxy(address[0], Convert.ToInt32(address[1]));
```

**Output**

```
123.34.345.23 <!-- Some Proxy here, seems good here -->
IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled( Index was outside the bounds of the array.)
```

Comment: it works for me. isn§t there a problem in getting the occoultProxy?

Comment: I'm guessing the value of `occoultProxy` is an IP without a port number.

Comment: I've tried your sample and that runs without issues. Are you sure that the strings you've passed to the statement always contained the semicolon?

Because you let the addresses be entered by the user, you should check the string for the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
        var occoultProxy = "123.34.123.45:8080";
        var parts = occoultProxy.Split(':');

        if (parts.Length == 2)
        {
            var proxy = new WebProxy(parts[0], Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AnExceptionToHandleInYourUi();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your input must not have a port segment, you can deal with this:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://" + occoultProxy));
```

Comment: or setting port to 80

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect local proxy with your local ip,please check if occoultProxy's value is "::1".